# Linear Functional on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Need some help understanding step two.

Suppose $\varphi$ is a linear functional on $V$. Then there is a unique vector $v \in V$ such that $\varphi (u) = \left \langle u, v \right \rangle$ for every $u \in V$

We start off with $\varphi (u) = \varphi (\left \langle u, e_1 \right \rangle e_1 + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \left \langle u , e_n \right \rangle e_n)$ where $(e_1 .... e_n ) $ is an orthogonal basis of $V$. Next $\varphi = \left \langle u, e_1 \right \rangle \varphi (e_1) +\cdot \cdot \cdot + \left \langle u,e_n \right \rangle \varphi (e_n) $, where did $\varphi (e_n ) $ come from?

$=\left \langle u, \varphi (e_1 )^* e_1 + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \varphi (e_n)^* e_n \right \rangle$

Comment: $\varphi$ is linear, and $\langle u, e_i\rangle$ are just numbers.

Comment: In other words, they're just doing $\varphi(ax + by + cz) = a \varphi(x) + b \varphi(y) + c \varphi(z)$, since $\varphi$ is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\varphi$ is a linear functional: $\varphi(av) = a\varphi(v)$ for every scalar $a$ and every vector $v$. Note that $\langle u,e_j\rangle$ is a scalar, and you have it.